# nsis radiobuttons, not on onclick to call function, but after click "next"

Tags: onclick, nsis

i´m new here and in nsis. I have a nsis script with some custompages an radiobuttons.

My problem is that when I choose a radiobutton the function is called immediately. And I want it after the "Next" click. I know thats because the `NSD_OnClick`, but is the a alternative?

Here is some code:

```
Function plugins
     nsDialogs::Create 1018
     Pop $Dialog

     ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 16u "Install Plugins?:"

     ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 20 40 100% 12u "Yes"
         Pop $hwnd
         ${NSD_AddStyle} $hwnd ${WS_GROUP}
         ${NSD_OnClick} $hwnd Yes
     ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 20 60 100% 12u "No"
         Pop $hwnd
         ${NSD_OnClick} $hwnd No

     nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function Yes
     ;Install Plugins...
FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the state of your radiobutton in the `Yes` callback and later in a leaving callback of your `plugins` custom page choose to install or not depending on the state.

Roughly :

```
Var isSelected

Function Yes
    StrCpy $isSelected 1
FunctionEnd

Function No
    StrCpy $isSelected 0
FunctionEnd

Function PlunginsLeavePage #<--you need to declare that in the "Page Custom"
    ${if} $isSelected = 1
        ;Install Plugins (this was formerly in the Yes function)
    ${endIf}
FunctionEnd
```